# NancyFx errors from async methods are not handled in OnError pipelines

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, nancy

I have NancyFX module with async POST method.

According to docs, all errors are handled like in here:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before%2C-After-and-OnError-pipelines

And errors are indeed handled if I code not async methods.

But I never get in callback when an exception is occurred within async methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been in the incorrect POST method signature which I declared as async method, but forgot to make it async.
And NancyFx engine didn't notice it.

```
Post["/order/validation", true] = (parameters, token) => Task.FromResult...
```

After I has corrected it to

```
Post["/order/validation", true] = async (parameters, token) => await ...
```

I started handling errors within

```
pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((ctx, exception) => {}
```

in Bootstrapper